# Object of prepositions and articles

Tags: word-usage, articles

How do I know whether to start the object of the preposition 'of' with an article or not? Can you illustrate these examples for me?

> by the effects of the civil war
>
> by the effects of an economic activity
>
> by the effects of climate change
>
> by the effects of food insecurity
>
> by the effects of globalization

If I wrote *by the effect of electric field*, would that be correct?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a foolproof way to figure this out, but here's a test you could try: Begin a sentence with the object of the preposition, and see if it reads better with or without the article:

- The civil war ended after eight long years of fighting.
- Economic activity lagged in the fourth quarter.
- Climate change is a grave concern in the scientific community.
- Food insecurity is a growing problem across the continent.
- Globalization is a trend in the 21st century.
- The electric field traps the ion.

I think that last sentence reads better with an article than without an article, so I'm guessing your sentence would read better if you wrote:

> by the effect of ***the*** electric field.

although it's hard to know for certain without reading your entire sentence or paragraph.

Comment: You are a Godsend.

Comment: +1 ... i think it also depends whether the specific object of the preposition has been discussed or mentioned before in the paragraph or not.... don’t you think?

Comment: @BavyanY - Sometimes that plays a role, sometimes not. Consider the famous question: _Who is the king of **the** jungle?_ It doesn't matter if there's been a previous mention of "jungle" – we include the article.

Comment: @BavyanYaldo You could also say _Protect the President!_ without mentioning it earlier, and with 20 people being the president of a different country. Being earlier mentioned or discussed is one of the reasons to use the determinate article, but not the only one.